# EventStore basics - what's the difference between Event Meta Data/MetaData and Event Data?

Tags: metadata, eventstoredb

I'm very much at the beginning of using / understanding [EventStore](https://geteventstore.com/) or get-event-store as it may be known here.

I've consumed the documentation regarding clients, projections and subscriptions and feel ready to start using on some internal projects.

One thing I can't quite get past - is there a guide / set of recommendations to describe the difference between event metadata and data ? I'm aware of the notional differences; Event data is 'Core' to the domain, Meta data for describing, but it is becoming quite philisophical.

I wonder if there are hard rules regarding implementation (querying etc).

Any guidance at all gratefully received!

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly copying (and paraphrasing) parts from [Szymon Kulec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700606/scooletz)'s blog post "[Enriching your events with important metadata](https://blog.scooletz.com/2015/08/11/enriching-your-events-with-important-metadata/)" (emphases mine):

> *But what information can be useful to store in the metadata, which info is worth to store despite the fact that it was not captured in
>   the creation of the model?*
>
> #### 1. Audit data
>
> - **who?** – simply store the user id of the action invoker
> - **when?** – the timestamp of the action and the event(s)
> - **why?** – the serialized intent/action of the actor
>
> #### 2. Event versioning
>
> The event sourcing deals with the effect of the actions. An action
>   executed on a state results in an action according to the current
>   implementation. Wait. The current implementation? Yes, the
>   implementation of your aggregate can change and it will either because
>   of bug fixing or introducing new features. **Wouldn’t it be nice if
>   the version, like a commit id (SHA1 for gitters) or a semantic version
>   could be stored with the event as well?** Imagine that you published a
>   broken version and your business sold 100 tickets before fixing a bug.
>   It’d be nice to be able which events were created on the basis of the
>   broken implementation. Having this knowledge you can easily compensate
>   transactions performed by the broken implementation.
>
> #### 3. Document implementation details
>
> It’s quite common to introduce canary releases, feature toggling and
>   A/B tests for users. With automated deployment and small code
>   enhancement all of the mentioned approaches are feasible to have on a
>   project board. If you consider the toggles or different implementation
>   coexisting in the very same moment, storing the version only may be
>   not enough. How about adding information which features were applied
>   for the action? Just create a simple set of features enabled, or map
>   feature-status and add it to the event as well. Having this and the
>   command, it’s easy to repeat the process. Additionally, it’s easy to
>   result in your A/B experiments. Just run the scan for events with A
>   enabled and another for the B ones.
>
> #### 4. Optimized combination of 2. and 3.
>
> If you think that this is too much, create a lookup for sets of
>   versions x features. It’s not that big and is repeatable across many
>   users, hence you can easily optimize storing the set elsewhere, under
>   a reference key. You can serialize this map and calculate SHA1, put
>   the values in a map (a table will do as well) and use identifiers to
>   put them in the event. There’s plenty of options to shift the load
>   either to the query (lookups) or to the storage (store everything as
>   named metadata).
>
> ### Summing up
>
> If you create an event sourced architecture, consider adding the
>   temporal dimension (version) and a bit of configuration to the
>   metadata. Once you have it, it’s much easier to reason about the
>   sources of your events and introduce tooling like compensation.
>   There’s no such thing like too much data, is there?

Answer (score 2):

I will share my experiences with you which may help.  I have been playing with akka-persistence, akka-persistence-eventstore and eventstore.  akka-persistence stores it's event wrapper, a PersistentRepr, in binary format.  I wanted this data in JSON so that I could:

- use projections
- make these events easily available to any other technologies

You can implement your own serialization for akka-persistence-eventstore to do this, but it still ended up just storing the wrapper which had my event embedded in a payload attribute.  The other attributes were all akka-persistence specific.  The author of akka-persistence-eventstore gave me some good advice, get the serializer to store the payload as the Data, and the rest as MetaData.  That way my event is now just the business data, and the metadata aids the technology that put it there in the first place.  My projections now don't need to parse out the metadata to get at the payload.