# What is the general approach to implement event versioning in Commanded using commanded/eventstore?

Tags: commanded

Would one put this versioning information into the [events' metadata](https://github.com/commanded/eventstore/blob/v0.15.1/lib/event_store/event_data.ex) or is there an already established best practice? Wouldn't want to reinvent the wheel if not necessary.

Comment: [Szymon Kulec's blog post](https://blog.scooletz.com/2015/08/11/enriching-your-events-with-important-metadata/) suggested the metadata option. (See also the [paraphrased summary of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205585/eventstore-basics-whats-the-difference-between-event-meta-data-metadata-and-e/54130807#54130807).)

Answer (score 0):

Commanded's next release has support for [event upcasting](https://github.com/commanded/commanded/blob/master/guides/Events.md#upcasting-events). This allows you upgrade events from any previous state and/or from their associated metadata.